# How to sync files programmatically to Azure storage in a way like Dropbox?

Tags: file-upload, synchronization, azure-blob-storage

I upload medical images to Azure storage. I used MS DICOM Server APIs and JS libraries provided by Microsoft to upload files to Azure Blob Storage. But they are not that fast. I expected to find something like dropbox method. Files synchronization is fast and resumable. What is the best method to run this? I expected very high traffic on my web application. Tens of clients will upload to my cloud storage at the same time.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

•   You can use Azure AzCopy utility for this purpose and you can use the following commands regarding Azcopy from powershell to sync the files from local storage to azure blob storage.

Syntax: -

‘azcopy sync '' 'https://.blob.core.windows.net/' –recursive’

Example: -

azcopy sync 'C:\myDirectory' 'https://mystorageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer' –recursive

•   You can also sync files between to and from a container and a local resource such that any modification to any file in the storage resources like deletion will be replicated to the other destination storage resource as well. You will have to add the ‘—delete-destination’ parameter to ‘true’ or ‘prompt’ for the files to be deleted from the destination storage resource.

•   For periodical syncing of data between the resources, you can create a windows task scheduler job to be run every 2 hours with the azcopy script to be invoked and run for syncing purposes. Also, please refer the below links for more information on various parameters to be used with azcopy for performing specific operations.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-blobs-synchronize

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-ref-azcopy-sync

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. the problem with AZcopy is that I need to install and configure it on each client's PC, while I'm providing this my services online via a web application.

Comment: You are welcome, but you can configure an azure storage link in the web application configured to upload all the images/documents in there and then sync them to your local system or personalized account by syncing it with azcopy. Link: - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/scenario-secure-app-access-storage?tabs=azure-portal%2Ccommand-line